# Error 403 Forbidden when starting Google Translate API in SDL Trados

Tags: localization, google-translate

I want to use `Google Translate API` in `SDL Trados`. I have my API, I've set up and enabled billing, entered the API key, but Google is returning the `403 Forbidden error`.

How can I get Trados and Google running together?

Comment: 403 is a very broad class of error in HTTP, and you'll need to provide more detail about the error response payload, the conditions under which the error appears, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I get an HTTP 403 error when I call the API.
    You may be exceeding your quota: either the daily billable total, or the limit on request characters per second.

```
To view or change usage limits for your project, or to request an increase to your quota, do the following:

    Go to the Google Developers Console.
    Select a project, or create a new one.
    In the sidebar on the left, expand APIs & auth.
    Click APIs.
    Click the name of an activated API you're interested in.
    Near the top of the info page for the API, click Quota.

If you have enabled billing for your project, clicking Quota takes you to a page where you can view and change quota-related settings.

If you have not enabled billing for your project, clicking Quota shows information about any free quota and limits that apply to this API.
```

Answer (score 0):

For the translate API, this means normally that you haven't connected a credit card to your account yet. Go to the developer console, add a credit card to billing and go to the quotums of the translate api. There's an 'Enable billing' button here that needs to be clicked.